# Xamarin binding count of ItemSource

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I need to enable/disable using XAML, a Picker based on the number of elements in it ItemsSource.

```xml
<Picker 
    ItemsSource="{Binding WoSpesaDett.DsTecnico}" 
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Valore}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding WoSpesaDett.Tecnico}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding ???}" 
    Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
```

I have tried to use `WoSpesaDett.DsTecnico.Count > 0` but it not works.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try [Converters](https://blog.xamarin.com/advanced-data-binding-for-ios-android-and-windows/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IValueConverter` for integer to bool:

```
public class IntToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int minimumLength = System.Convert.ToInt32 (parameter);
        return (int)value >= minimumLength;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:**

If you need to change the visibility of your Picker only once (not in dynamic manner), then create a converter like other answers pointing out.

**Otherwise:**

In theory dynamically hiding or showing a UI control is very simple. All you have to do is to introduce a boolean property in your model that should look like this for example:

```
public bool MyPickerShouldBeVisible => WoSpesaDett.DsTecnico.Count > 0;
```

Now the problem is that you need to notify your `View` about changes related to `MyPickerShouldBeVisible`. I am usually using [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to handle the `INotifyPropertyChange` stuff. Using it you could mark your `DsTecnico` property with a special attribute `AlsoNotifyFor(nameof(MyPickerShouldBeVisible))` to make this solution work.

Here is a full example, ViewModel data is simplified:

```
// INotifyPropertyChanged should be handled by `Fody.PropertyChanged`
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public IList<string> MyData { get; set; }
  [AlsoNotifyFor(nameof(MyPickerShouldBeVisible))]
  public bool ShouldShowPicker => MyData.Any();
}
```

Using the example above, will result in a dynamic behaviour of you picker.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a bool in your binding context:

```
public bool PickerShouldBeEnabled
{
    get { return WoSpesaDett.DsTecnico.Count > 0; } //returns true if there are more than 0 elements
}
```

or for better performance use linq "Any()", if u just wanna enable it if there are **any** elements in the list

```
public bool PickerShouldBeEnabled
{
    get { return WoSpesaDett.DsTecnico.Any(); } //returns true if there are any elements
}
```

Or you can create an [IValueConverter](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.Binding.Converter/) that takes the list as the value and returns true based on the count of the list elements.
I could give you a basic converter for this situation as well.